# Multiple variable selectors jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table, each "< tr >" has a div. Each div has a dynamic class (for example) ->

```
class="name<?php echo $id?>"
```

Now each "< tr >" also has another  which is "display:none" by default.
Also in each "< tr >" is another another div containing simple text "Open".

What I'm trying to achieve is.... when I press the open text, it should "display:block" the div for EXACTLY THAT "< tr >" and not for ALL..

What I tried is:

```
<script>

var adida = <?php echo $this->row->id; ?>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#vj"+adida).click(function(){
    jQuery(".opt"+adida).toggle();
    });
});
```

I've putted this script into EACH "< tr >", at top... but it doesn't seem to work.. nothing happens... can somebody please help me. Thank you

P.S. If I look through source code at the script at the row ->

```
var adida = <?php echo $this->row->id; ?>
```

I can see it shows CORRECT... so in each "< tr >" it shows for example

```
var adida = 559;
```

Comment: It would be ***a lot*** easier to just use one common class on all the elements and regular DOM traversal methods to find the related elements to each instance etc.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with html?

Comment: are the `adida` defined in the global scope - if so it may cause you js problems if you are declaring them for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about sticking uniquely identifying classes on the table rows. When the click event fires, you can get the element that was clicked on from the context. From that you can navigate through the DOM up to the table row and then down to the div you want.

For [example](http://jsbin.com/cotayuso/1/edit?html,output):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button>open</button></td>
    <td><div style="display: none;">Hidden by default</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button>open</button></td>
    <td><div style="display: none;">Hidden by default</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button>open</button></td>
    <td><div style="display: none;">Hidden by default</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button>open</button></td>
    <td><div style="display: none;">Hidden by default</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    jQuery('table button').on('click', function (evt) {
      var $button = $(this);
      var $tr = $button.parents('tr');
      var $div = $tr.find('div');
      $div.show();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Yes. this is it. it works with this code perfectly :) thank you

Comment: Hi. Can you please help with one more thing on this, at the moment if you click on another "open" button the OTHER that was opened STILL stays opened... is there a way so if I open one <div> the other "opened" <div> closes...? Thank you

Comment: Hi. Can you please help with one more thing on this, at the moment if you click on another "open" button the OTHER that was opened STILL stays opened... is there a way so if I open one <div> the other "opened" <div> closes...? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Avoid multiple event handlers since a uniq action has to be executed relative to the button clicked, use event delegation instead by attaching the event on the first common ancestor.

Assuming this HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td><button>Click here</button></td>
    <td><div>misc content</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button>Click here</button></td>
     <td><div>misc content</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#mytable').on('click', function(e){
          var $b = $(e.target);
          if($b.is('button')){
            $b.closest('tr').find('div').show();
            // eventually e.stopPropagation(); AND/OR return false;
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Style

```
#mytable div{
    display:none
}
```